# How to handle click events on child components in React.js, is there a React "way"?

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to create/prototype a widget that has a search filter and 2-panels that have a key-value/parent-child relationship. The right panel contains categories, the left panel has interests that are associated with an individual category. The category rows are selectable to show the associated interest checkboxes. I haven't gotten to the point of trying to understand how to update the form submission with the checkboxes, first I need to understand more about the correct way to make the data flow.

This is my first foray into React and I know that React encourages one-way data flow. I feel that I am updating the interests panel incorrectly by using jQuery to handle the events. I'd like to know some alternative ways to update the interests panel.

From what I've read, in order to update parent (I believe its referred to as owner in the React docs) components you need to define callbacks on the child/ownee components. I'd appreciate an explanation of this and also if I'm incorrectly using interests in state vs props. I was attempting to only have the Search filter & the checkboxes be a part of the state for the widget, because I read that filterable data should belong in props.

UPDATE: I changed the interests to be initialized in getDefaultProps, so now I'm using them as props. I think this is more the React way, am I correct? I also changed the way that interests are updated by changing the handleCategoryRowClick function. I think I am doing things the more React way now, but would still love any advice that anyone with more experience using React could give, thank you.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```jsx
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var InterestRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label>{this.props.interest.name}</label>
                <input type="checkbox" ref={this.props.key} value={this.props.key} />
            </div>
        )
   }
});

var InterestPanel = React.createClass({
    var interestPanel = this;
    var rows = [];

    render: function() {
        var rows = [];
        var i = 0;

        _(this.props.interests).each(function (interest) {
            rows.push(<InterestRow interest={interest} key={interest.value} />);
        });

        return (
            <form>{rows}</form>
        )
    }
});

var CategoryRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li onClick={this.props.handleClick.bind(null, this.props.interests)}>{this.props.category}</li>
        )
    }
});

var CategoriesPanel = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    var categoriesPanel = this;
    var rows = [];
    var categories = [];
    var interests = [];
    var interestSet = [];
    var missedSet = [];
    var lastCategory = null;
    var category;
    var interest;
    var i = 0;

    _.each(categoriesPanel.props.data, function (datum) {
        name = datum.name;
        value = datum.targeting_value;
        category = name.split('/')[0];
        interest = {name: name.split('/')[1], value: value}

        if (_.contains(interest.name.toLowerCase(), categoriesPanel.props.searchText.toLowerCase())) {
            if (category !== lastCategory) {
                if (interestSet.length > 0) {
                    interests.push(interestSet.concat(missedSet));
                }

                lastCategory = category;
                categories.push(category);
                interestSet = [];
                interestSet.push(interest);
                missedSet = [];
            } else {
                if (!_.contains(categories, category)) {
                    categories.push(category);
                    interestSet.push(interest);
                } else {
                    interestSet.push(interest);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (category !== lastCategory) {
                if (interestSet.length > 0) {
                    interests.push(interestSet.concat(missedSet));
                }

                lastCategory = category;
                interestSet = [];
                missedSet = [];
                missedSet.push(interest);
            } else {
                missedSet.push(interest);
            }
        }
    });

    if (interestSet.length > 0) {
        interests.push(interestSet.concat(missedSet));
    }

    var interestsObject = _.zipObject(categories, interests);

    _.each(interestsObject, function (interestSet, category) {
        i++;
        rows.push(<CategoryRow category={category} key={i} interests={interestSet} handleClick={categoriesPanel.props.handleClick} />)
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>{rows}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}
});

var SearchBar = React.createClass({
    handleChange: function() {
        this.props.onUserInput(
            this.refs.searchTextInput.getDOMNode().value
        )
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search Interests..."
                    value={this.props.searchText}
                    ref="searchTextInput"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </form>
        );
     }
});

var InterestsTable = React.createClass({
loadDataFromTwitter: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            this.setProps({data: data});
        }.bind(this)
    });
},
getInitialState: function() {
   return {
       searchText: ''
   }
},
getDefaultProps: function() {
   return {
       data: [],
       interests: []
   }
},
componentWillMount: function() {
    this.loadDataFromTwitter();
},
handleUserInput: function(searchText) {
   this.setState({
       searchText: searchText
   });
},
handleCategoryRowClick: function(interests) {
    this.setProps({
        interests: interests
    });
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <SearchBar
                searchText={this.state.searchText}
                onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
            />
            <CategoriesPanel
                data={this.props.data}
                searchText={this.state.searchText}
                handleClick={this.handleCategoryRowClick}
            />
            <InterestsPanel
                interests={this.props.interests}
                searchText={this.state.searchText}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
});

React.renderComponent(
     <InterestsTable url="/api/interests" />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- There is some lingering jQuery that can be removed:

```js
    componentDidMount: function() {
      $(document).on("handleCategoryRowClick", this.handleCategoryRowClick);
    },
```

- Treat `props` as immutable as often as possible and React life
  cycle methods will work as expected. In this case, `interests` should be
  `state` instead of `props` because the `InterestsTable` component owns
  and modifies it; it's not passed in by the component's parent:

```js
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        interests: [],
        searchText: ""
      };
    },
    handleCategoryRowClick: function(e, interests) {
      this.setState({
        interests: interests
      });
    },
```

Comment: I forgot to remove the jQuery function, but my code no longer has it... From the React docs [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live) it seems to encourage using props for any data that can be computed via other state or props. Is there a benefit to using state vs props? The way I currently have it setup as props and the functionality is working.

Comment: I updated my code, ssorallen... Does this seem "React-ish" to you? Also, currently the search filter updates the checkbox inputs that are on the DOM. If a checkbox is checked and then the search filter updates the DOM, how can I store the value of the checked checkbox in React? Would I have to use jQuery to grab and store that data on the client before sending it to the server?

Comment: P.S. I know the CategoriesPanel code needs some refactoring, I'm going to refactor it just wanted to get everything working first. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: [`setProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setprops) can only be called on a root component, a component rendered via `React.renderComponent`. That is possible so the thing calling render, which is not a React component itself, can update the data in the component. A component should not call `setProps` on itself, even if it happens to be the root.

Comment: Is there any trade off using state vs props in this situation, since it seems the same thing is accomplishable with props? Its clearly better practice to use setState instead of setProps, but isn't it also best practice to have as little mutability/state as possible? As I mentioned this is my 1st time using React and I'm sorry for asking so many questions, I'd just like to understand these nuances as much as possible. Also, is there a better way to write the conditional filter based upon the state.searchText in CategoriesPanel? I suppose I could write smaller functions on the component...

Comment: and then call them inside the render function, but I was wondering if maybe I was incorrectly passing the data or missing some less complex approach to filter the CategoryRows to build and the props.interests to pass into those CategoryRows that get filtered again in the InterestsPanel. I'm taking a similar approach to the Thinking In React widgets search filter. Are there any places to find more advanced examples using React? I've found Khan Academy's GitHub repo and the basic examples provided by FB.

Comment: It is best practice to have data flow in a single direction and events be the source of data changes. Functionally `state` and `props` will work the same in your example, but in general `props` is an immutable structure passed from a parent component to a child component; `state` is a mutable structure maintained by a component. Your example is using `props` the way `state` is intended to be used.

Comment: `CategoriesPanel` is acting as both a model and a controller/view. The filtering could live on a `Category` object that gets passed through the component hierarchy, and the `CategoriesPanel` could simply render the categories passed to it. It's not simplifying in the sense of reducing lines of code, but it is separating concerns. It would make the component's render function shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: ssorallen, thank you so much for your help! Do you recommend any resources for gaining a better understanding of React besides the docs? I've also watched all the Egghead.io screencasts as well.